# Assembly x86 - memory addressing for variables (checking my answers)

Tags: assembly, x86

```
.DATA
var1 DD 0XADCAEF87, -33, 33, 0X33
var2 DW -12, 1100B,765oct,33h,-154
var3 times 3 db "AB",1,10b,"12"
```

Assuming starting address is F000H in memory, what is the address for var2,var3 and also draw how each array would like in memory segment.

My attemp:
var1=F000H

var2= F000H +16 = F010H

var3 = F000H + 16 + 10 = F01AH

Are those correct?

And for the segment

[image]

Are my answers correct?

Comment: 0005 to 0008, 0101 are wrong. Remove 0X in 000C.

Comment: "765oct" is not valid NASM syntax.

Answer (score 0):

WORD memory variable with negative value, for instance `-12` are sign-extended to 16 bits, e.g. `FFF4`, whose bytes are stored reversed in memory (due to the little-endian architecture).

In order to check your homework you should ask your assembler to produce *listing file*.
I created this source file `mostfa.asm`:

```
     EUROASM DmpWidth=40, NoWarn=2101
[.DATA]
$    EQU 0F000H
var1 DD 0XADCAEF87, -33, 33, 0X33
var2 DW -12, 1100B,765q,33h,-154
var3 db 3*b "AB",1,10b,"12"
```

and assembled it by [€ASM](https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/) with the command `euroasm mostfa.asm` which generated listing `mostfa.asm.lst`:

```
|                                      |     EUROASM DUMPWIDTH=40, NoWarn=2101
|[.DATA]                               |[.DATA]
|F000:                                 |$    EQU 0F000H
|F000:87EFCAADDFFFFFFF2100000033000000 |var1 DD 0XADCAEF87, -33, 33, 0X33
|F010:F4FF0C00F501330066FF             |var2 DW -12, 1100B,765q,33h,-154
|F01A:41424142414201023132             |var3 db 3*b "AB",1,10b,"12"
```